# Flex embed swf : blank if embedded with spark works if linked or with mx

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a very strange error in Flex

```
<s:Image  width="27" height="39" source="assets/cards/down.swf"/>
```

Works perfectly (down.swf is a swf with no script inside at all)

But

```
<s:Image  width="27" height="39" source="@Embed('assets/cards/down.swf')"/>
```

Shows me nothing at all !

Any idea why ?
(I tried with PNG and JPG and with PNG/JPEG everything works normally.

**and it works with**

```
<mx:Image  width="27" height="39" source="@Embed('assets/cards/down.swf')"/>
```

Regards

Comment: Instead of s:Image try s:BitMapImage .  I'm guessing here; but I assume the embed turns it into a ByteArray and that the s:Image does not the facility to process a ByteArray; but mx:Image does.  [Just a guess without reviewing respective code behind them]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You're trying to load a SWF using an `Image` component.

[`<mx:Image>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html) extends the [`<mx:SWFLoader>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) class. As such, you can imagine that an `<mx:Image>` therefore has the ability to load SWF files.

However, the [`<s:Image>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html) does not extend `<mx:SWFLoader>`, it extends `SkinnableComponent`.

As such, you cannot use `<s:Image>` to work with SWF files like you could with `<mx:Image>`. I would recommend you use a `<mx:SWFLoader>` instead.